# AWS: How can I get Cloudfront to trigger S3 redirection rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have Cloudfront working for existing objects on S3.

However, I'm currently trying to get it to trigger the redirection rule for missing keys and objects.

To give you context, I am doing this because I'm trying to trigger a lambda function from S3 so that I can generate different image sizes on the fly.

This is my S3 redirection rule + Static Web Hosting config, which currently isn't even getting triggered:

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <KeyPrefixEquals/>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>foobar.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>default/imageResize?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

[image]

Here is my Error Page config for Cloudfront:

[image]

However even after waiting for my cloudfront distribution to finish deploying, when I try to visit Cloudfront with a non existent S3 key for my existing S3 bucket, it is stil sending back a 403 and not a 404, so I don't think my config did anything.

[image]

What setup am I missing to get cloudfront to trigger my redirection rule whenever I try to make a GET request to a non existent object?

Answer (score 0):

The redirect will work with s3 endpoint instead of CloudFront, CloudFront bypass the redirection rule because the routing rule are set for static hosting.

**Redirect for an HTTP error**

> Suppose that when a requested object is not found, you want to redirect requests to an Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance. Add a redirection rule so that when an HTTP status code `404 (Not Found)` is returned, the site visitor is redirected to an Amazon EC2 instance that handles the request.

```
  <RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals >
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <HostName>ec2-11-22-333-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>report-404/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
    </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
  </RoutingRules>
```

[how-to-page-redirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html)

So it will work with s3 endpoint

```
http://mybucket.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/file404.pdg
```

it will redirect to `ec2-11-22-333-44.compute-1.amazonaws.com` base on the above rule.

To make the above working with cloud, you can look into the [ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/450940/why-s3-website-redirect-location-is-not-followed-by-cloudfront).

> I created a Cloudfront distribution with a custom origin pointing to the S3 static website hostname instead of the **bucket hostname**. In the OP's case, the desired origin would be.

```
mysite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

[why-s3-website-redirect-location-is-not-followed-by-cloudfront](https://serverfault.com/questions/450940/why-s3-website-redirect-location-is-not-followed-by-cloudfront)

- Create distribution
- Specify S3 static website URL in the domain name instead of s3 bucket name
- The redirect will work as expected
  [image]

Comment: When I do this it seems to redirect properly to the lambda function but it returns an error saying I've been redirected too many times. Do you know how I can fix this? When I run the lambda function directly using the "test" button, it works so I think it's a problem with my S3 redirection rule?